# Powershell redirect to variable value containing colon

Tags: powershell, redirection, string, escape-characters

Is there a way to use a variable whose value contains the colon character as a filename string in a command-line redirect? Powershell always treats the colon as a drive separator, regardless of escape characters. How can this be done using the colon as a character literal contained in the output filename?

Example:

```
$colonVar = "Colon:string"
echo "fileContents" > "file$colonVar.txt"
```

yields

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'fileColon' does not exist.

Can we instead write "fileContents" to a file named "fileColon:string.txt"?

I have not been successful using any combination of single or double quotation marks, escape characters, parentheses, or dollar sign and parentheses in the string value or the redirect string. The portion of the string after the colon is always treated as a drive.

(Using Powershell 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you can't have a file with a colon in it's name, so it's not PowerShell that's preventing it, it's the file system.  Strip out the colon, and/or replace it with a character that's valid for filenames.

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177506:

```
A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: 
\ / : * ? " < > |
```

Comment: On the other hand, it can be worked around... well, some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename

Comment: Thanks. I assumed from the error message that powershell, not the system, was blocking the command from succeeding but it makes sense that it's blocked at the OS level because the OS doesn't allow it anyway. For the record, powershell supports inline text replacement, e.g. `echo "fileContents" > "file$colonVar.txt".replace(":","_")` or `$colonVar = "Colon:string".replace(":","_")`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with redirection or `Out-File` or `Tee-Object` in PowerShell as far as I can tell. You can write to a file with a name that has a colon using `Set-Content`, but that would make it an Alternate Data Stream for the file with the name before the colon. Redirection to these [Alternate Data Streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/c54dec26-1551-4d3a-a0ea-4fa40f848eb3) is possible in the command prompt.

`Set-Content -Path ".\file$colonVar.txt" -Value "fileContents"` works, but if you browse there in the file system you'll only see a file named literally "fileColon" with no colon in the name and no extension and no contents.
If you want to access the stream, you can use `Get-Content -Path ".\file$colonVar.txt"`, but I don't know a way of accessing that stream with most Windows applications.

See my question for how I found this possibility out. [Colon in filename creates pseudo folder. How do I see what's inside?](https://superuser.com/questions/1540889/colon-in-filename-creates-pseudo-folder-how-do-i-see-whats-inside)