# Why ":foo" expands to "<working dir>\:foo"

Tags: powershell

(Using `echo.exe` of Git for Windows (MSYS2))

```
# expands to an invalid ADS-ish path
PS D:\path> echo.exe :bar
D:\path\:bar
# expands with double quote
PS D:\path> echo.exe ":bar"
D:\path\:bar
# expands with backquote
PS D:\path> echo.exe "`:bar"
D:\path\:bar
# expands with wsl and cmd, so not MSYS2 related
PS D:\path> wsl -e "echo" ":bar"
D:\path\:bar
PS D:\path> cmd /c "echo" ":bar"
D:\path\:bar
# not expands with single quote
PS D:\path> echo.exe ':bar'
:bar
# not expands if not starts with colon
PS D:\path> echo.exe "foo:bar"
foo:bar
# not expands if not spawns new process
PS D:\path> ":123"
:123
PS D:\path> echo ":123"
:123
```

Research so far:

1. It is PROBABLY NOT related to [Alternative Data Stream](https://superuser.com/q/1540889/702169). It is just passing command line. What's more, this generates an ADS-looking path, however, it is not a valid ADS path. (Maybe it is trying?)
2. It is NOT related to MSYS2. Same behavior with `wsl -e "echo"` and `cmd /c "echo"` is also verified.
3. It is NOT related to [Variable expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8386219/6202760), since not any variables here.
4. Tested with different versions of PowerShell, it should be due to a change between `v7.1.3..v7.2.0-preview.1`
5. It should be an issue in spawning new processes.

Requested by @LievenKeersmaekers
[image]

Comment: Why are you explicitly using `echo` from MSYS2 and how do you come to the conclusion that Powershell expansion is to blame? What does a simple `":foo"` returns? If that returns a path, it's Powershell. If it doesn't return a path, its `echo.exe`.

Comment: An almost sure way to figure this out is by using Procmon from sysinternals. Have it run, run your command, stop it and search for `echo.exe` being called. You can view the parameters that get passed tot `echo.exe` and which `echo.exe` is being called.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers as said I have tried many different programs, including `wsl`, that all displays wrong expansion. (Later I found that `cmd /c echo ":123"` can reproduce as well, which is much easier to go.) What's more, PowerShell v7.1.3 is alright but v7.2.0-preview.1 expands strangely. This behavior changes with PowerShell versions ALONE.

Comment: You might be on to something but all we currently have is what you post here and I have no way to verify that so what does a simple  `":123"` return in Powershell? What does a simple `echo ":123"` returns in cmd? Can you post what gets passed to `echo` using the Procmon suggestion?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers first of all, `echo` does not create process, it is an alias to `Write-Output`, which is a CmdLet. Using `cmd /c echo ":123"`, it shows `Command line: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c echo D:\path\:123`.

Comment: `echo` is an alias but `echo.exe` most definitely is not. I have yet to see you present anything I've asked. If you don't want help, you should just say so.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers So you should not say `echo` but `echo.exe`. I have provided ProcMon event command line. Did you ask for anything else? If you just playing with your words and don't want to help, you should just leave.

Comment: What does a simple `":123"`  return in Powershell? What does a simple `echo ":123"` returns in cmd?

Comment: Can you confirm that executing `cmd /c echo ":123"`  using pwsh v7.1.3 has a different command line than using pwsh 7.2.0-preview.1? Can you share a screenshot of that? If that is the case, I would strongly suspect a bug in the preview version in passing parameters to newly created processes.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers The ProcMon output is in my comment reply, which I copied here. I think it useless and off-topic, since I have done some control variables. Different programs from different developers showing the very same result but different version of PowerShell or different PowerShell syntax (`":123"` vs `':123'`) diverges. ;;; `":123"` and `echo ":123"` just prints `:123`, indicating that there must be something when spawning new process with double quote syntax. At this point, I found this question maybe more fit to StackOverflow and even more fit to GitHub Issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124550/discussion-between-lieven-keersmaekers-and-inq).